# Do property lists in Common Lisp refer to some global state?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

The code below has `z` as a local variable, yet it behaves as if it is a global:

```
(defun foo (m)
  (let ((z '(stuff nil)))
    (push m (getf z 'stuff))
    (print z)))

(foo 1)
(foo 2)
(foo 3)
```

I would expect the output to be

```
(STUFF (1)) 
(STUFF (2)) 
(STUFF (3)) 
T
```

but when running it with SBCL I see

```
(STUFF (1)) 
(STUFF (2 1)) 
(STUFF (3 2 1)) 
T
```

Why is this the case? Is this behaviour peculiar to property lists?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected persistence of data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790192/unexpected-persistence-of-data)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `foo`, `z` is bound to the literal expression `'(stuff nil)`.  The function destructively alters `z`, thus destructively changing the value of the literal.  How LISP behaves in circumstances like this is implementation-dependent.  Some implementations will obediently alter the literal value (as in your case).  Other implementations place literals in read-only memory locations and will fail if you attempt to modify those literals.

To get the desired behaviour, use `COPY-LIST` to make a copy of the literal that can be safely modified:

```
(defun foo (m)
  (let ((z (copy-list '(stuff nil))))
    (push m (getf z 'stuff))
    (print z)))
```

Comment: I think the more idiomatic way would be to use `LIST`, as in `(let ((z (list 'stuff nil))) ...)`